# pandas iterrows then match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` like this:

```
C1  C2      C3       C4
A   TV      /r/tv3   NaN
B   Music   Pop      /r/pop
C   /r/foo  NaN      NaN
```

I need to iterate through each row and get the value of the first column and then find the value of the column which starts with /r/. So the output should look like this:

```
A    /r/tv3
B    /r/pop
C    /r/foo
```

What is the fastest pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `where` after `startswith`

```
df.where(df.apply(lambda x : x.str.startswith(pat='/r/'),axis=1)).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
Out[680]: 
C1
A    /r/tv3
B    /r/pop
C    /r/foo
dtype: object
```

Comment: awesome! but it doesn't output the first column (i.e. C1). It only gives the second column

Comment: @msmazh adding `.reset_index()` at the end